# IntelliJ community edition JSP Syntax highlighting

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

I just downloaded IntelliJ 15.0.1 Community Edition because i'm sick of Eclipse and it looks horrible on my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). Everything was going pretty well until I saw that syntax highlighting in JSP files was not working.

I went to Settings/Editor/File Types

In the Recognized File Types,among other options, I have  this one:

JSP Files (syntax Highlighting Only)

When I select it I can see in the registered patterns: *.jsp, *.tag which is exactly what I want ... but it doesn't work ...any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Community edition doesn't have support for JEE projects, so I'm surprised the syntax highlighting is even there.

Comment: I also read that but since it says (syntax Highlighting Only) I thought it should work. It says exactly the same thing for JavaScript files and syntax highlighting in that case does work. And JavaScript is supported only on the ultimate edition..

Comment: In any case you can try out the full version for free for a month, so you could install it and try to create a proper JEE project in it. If the syntax highlighting doesn't even work then, you apparently found a regression bug. If not... well IntelliJ is meant to be licensed. If you want to use something for free, use something free. I switched from Eclipse to Netbeans myself and couldn't be happier.

Comment: I did what you said. It worked perfectly on the Ultimate Edition so I lost hope because it's expensive.  I found a way to make Eclipse look decent on my laptop. I had to edit a .css file. Here's what I did http://askubuntu.com/questions/156910/how-to-change-eclipse-font-sizes

Comment: I have edited @Roland's answer, it should now be the accepted one.

Answer (score 14):

IntelliJ IDEA allows to manually add syntax highlighting settings in "Settings > File Types" even in the Community Edition **BUT it ignores these settings after a restart**.

These settings are stored in the user's home directory at e.g. ~/.IdeaIC2016.1/config/filetypes/*.xml. Unfortunately, after a restart of the IDE, these settings are NOT read, therefore it seems useless to configure any settings :-(

```
<filetype binary="false" description="JSP files (syntax highlighting only)" name="JSP">
  <highlighting>
    <options>
      <option name="LINE_COMMENT" value="" />
      <option name="COMMENT_START" value="&lt;%--" />
      <option name="COMMENT_END" value="--%&gt;" />
      <option name="HEX_PREFIX" value="#" />
      <option name="NUM_POSTFIXES" value="" />
      <option name="HAS_BRACES" value="true" />
      <option name="HAS_BRACKETS" value="true" />
      <option name="HAS_PARENS" value="true" />
      <option name="HAS_STRING_ESCAPES" value="true" />
    </options>
    <keywords keywords="%&gt;;&lt;%!;&lt;%@;include;page;taglib" ignore_case="false" />
    <keywords2 keywords="c:choose;c:if;c:otherwise;c:set;c:url;c:when;fmt:message;fmt:setBundle;fmt:setLocale;s:eval;s:message;sec:authorize" />
    <keywords3 keywords="html;head;title;meta;header;nav;section;footer;body;a;br;hr;div;form;input;button;submit;textarea;p;script;noscript;span;style;table;td;th;tr;ol;ul;li;label;i;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;img" />
    <keywords4 keywords="if;else;function;for;do;let;this;while;with;thows;true;false;char;case;continue;alert;confirm;console;length;return;var;boolean;forms;" />
  </highlighting>
</filetype>
```

(~/.IdeaIC2016.1/config/filetypes/JSP.xml )

IntelliJ Community Edition also ignores any file-type settings for CSS-files that could look like this:

```
<filetype binary="false" description="CSS files (syntax highlighting only)" name="CSS">
  <highlighting>
    <options>
      <option name="LINE_COMMENT" value="" />
      <option name="COMMENT_START" value="/*" />
      <option name="COMMENT_END" value="*/" />
      <option name="HEX_PREFIX" value="#" />
      <option name="NUM_POSTFIXES" value="" />
      <option name="HAS_BRACES" value="true" />
    </options>
    <keywords keywords="a;body;button;div;font;font-face;form;frame;h1;h2;h3;h4;iframe;img;import;input;li;link;media;nav;ol;option;p;select;span;table;td;th;title;tr;u;ul;video" ignore_case="false" />
    <keywords2 keywords="  box-shadow;background;background-color;border;border-radius;bottom;box-shadow;color;content;cursor;display;float;font-family;font-size;font-weight;height;left;line-height;list-style-type;margin;margin-bottom;margin-left;margin-right;margin-top;outline;overflow;padding;padding-bottom;padding-left;padding-right;padding-top;position;right;text-align;text-decoration;text-transform;top;vertical-align;white-space;width;z-index;zoom" />
    <keywords3 keywords="em;pt;px;rgb;rgba" />
    <keywords4 keywords="!important;active;after;before;hover;none;visited" />
  </highlighting>
</filetype>
```

(~/.IdeaIC2016.1/config/filetypes/CSS.xml)

Comment: In IntelliJ Community Edition 2017.2, it does autoload the files...PROVIDED you add an association to them in the XML. So, in your JSP example, you must add `<extensionMap>
    <mapping ext="jsp" />
  </extensionMap>` below the root `<filetype>` element, and it autoloads it. You also have to rename it: use `<filetype binary="false" description="MyJSP" name="MyJSP">`. Also remove the `*.jsp` association from JSP in "Settings > File Types".

Comment: @abhidivekar I'm using IntelliJ Community 2017.3.3 and all you have to do is go to "Settings > Editor > File Types". Under "Recognized File Types", click on HTML, then under "Registered Patterns" add *.jsp .. Nothing else is required.

Answer (score 6):

You must create a own JSP File Type e.g. "My JSP".
The registered File Patterns must be:

*.j?p

*.j?pf

(*.jsp are reserved)

In the default File Type: "JSP Files (syntax Highlighting Only)" you must delete the File Patterns *.jsp.
Set it to e.g. `*.jjj`.

Then the IntelliJ Idea saves this File Type and after a Restart the Settings are still available.

Comment: What? What do you by mean setting them to `*.jjj`?

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ supports JSP syntax highlighting, but strangely none of the syntax is predefined. It allows us to define the syntax though if you double click "JSP Files (syntax highlighting only)".

The + / - buttons below allows to add keywords and 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 tabs give different syntax colours. It is not possible to add all HTML/JSP keywords manually one by one but I've defined most common used keywords and it is much better than having no highlighting at all.

[image: Edit File Type]

Comment: Would you be able to export the list you have already made? To make it easier on me? :)

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have it :(

Comment: @uesports135 Just use the lists in the first answer.

Comment: Too bad IntelliJ doesn't remember the changes.