# Idea intellij: JSP file color and font settings

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, ide

I have a `jsp` file and it doesn't highlight keywords and tags the way it does with `html` files. I tried going to `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts` but there is no `JSP` in the list there, only `Java` and `HTML`. How would I set my own fonts and colors to `jsp` files, similar to those of `html` files?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Comment: alternative JSP file syntax color solution check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35439692/17979026

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, because there is [no support for JSP in the Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html). If you are already using Ultimate, check that you [didn't disable](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html) JSP related plug-ins.

If you want just the basic syntax highlighting for JSP files in the Community Edition, you can use TextMate Bundles support [similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16451778/104891).