# How to get e.g. registration.jsp view appear correctly in browser?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, intellij-idea, view

I am following this tutorial for a login and registration functionality in a Spring Boot web application: https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-security-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-hsql-jsp/

I can't get the views to display properly - instead of e.g. the registration.jsp view page, I see the following string on screen, which is returned by my GET registration controller method: https://ibb.co/XXXtdSZ

I am new to Java, Spring Boot and even newer to JSP.
I am using IntelliJ Community Edition 2017.3.5 and I had a notification that .jsp files are not supported. Following this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36572413/11451547, I went to Settings - File Types - HTML under Recognized File Types, and I added a new registered pattern, .*jsp, overriding the already existing registered pattern for JSP Files (syntax Highlighting Only). The message that .jsp was not supported disappeared but I still don't see the view pages properly.

In my registration.jsp I see a lot of 'namespace e.g.'form' is not bound' notifications. In my login.jsp, which has the same display issue (on screen I see the string 'login' instead of the login view), I have one notification - 'Namespace 'c' is not bound'.

Could you help with some ideas on how to display the views correctly?

Thank you!

This is the respective part of my controller (maybe I am wrong in adding @ModelAttribute to GET registration twice, this is part of the amendments I did to the tutorial code but e.g. my GET login controller method is the same as in the tutorial):

```
@GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

        return "registration";
    }

@PostMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, @ModelAttribute("roleId") Long roleId, BindingResult bindingResult) { //diff w tutorial
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);
//        userValidator.validate(roleId, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }
        userService.saveUser(userForm, roleId);

        securityService.autoLogin(userForm.getUserName(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
        if (error != null)
            model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and/or password is invalid.");

        if (logout != null)
            model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping({"/", "/welcome"})
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        return "welcome";
    }
```

My registration.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Create an account</title>

      <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="userForm" modelAttribute="roleId" class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create Your Account</h2>
            <spring:bind path="userName">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                    <form:input type="text" path="userName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your username"
                                autofocus="true"></form:input>
                    <form:errors path="userName"></form:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>

            <spring:bind path="password">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                    <form:input type="password" path="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password"></form:input>
                    <form:errors path="password"></form:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>

            <spring:bind path="passwordConfirm">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                    <form:input type="password" path="passwordConfirm" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Confirm your password"></form:input>
                    <form:errors path="passwordConfirm"></form:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form:form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My login.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Log in with your account details</title>

      <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="POST" action="${contextPath}/login" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-heading">Log In</h2>
        <div class="form-group ${error != null ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <span>${message}</span>
            <input name="userName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your username"
                   autofocus="true"/>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password"/>
            <span>${error}</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button>
            <h4 class="text-center"><a href="${contextPath}/registration">Create an Account</a></h4>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My welcome.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>

    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
        <form id="logoutForm" method="POST" action="${contextPath}/logout">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        </form>

        <h2>Welcome ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a onclick="document.forms['logoutForm'].submit()">Logout</a></h2>
    </c:if>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The respective part of my application.yml file:

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: 'off'
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inspire_me_db?useSSL=false
    username: springuser
    password: ThePassword
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  flyway:
    baselineOnMigrate: true
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /
      suffix: .jsp
  messages:
    basename: validation
```

The respective part of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My package structure:

https://ibb.co/Qr2dmNr

Comment: I use Spring MVC but not Spring Boot. But it definitely looks like it's not using your JSP view resolver. Thus, not converting the returned "registration" string into serving `/registration.jsp`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I read a lot about view resolvers but still trying to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try registering your jsp view resolver as follows :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

Or you can also specify jsp as the view resolver in Spring-boot by providing the following in `application.properties` or yml :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Verify that the prefix provided points to the correct directory in which the jsp files reside.Usually the jsp files are put under `src/main/WEB_INF/view` .

Also since you are using spring-boot , if you don't have the appropriate dependencies to compile the `jsp` add the following to the pom :

```
<!-- JSTL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- To compile JSP files -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and variations of it.
Now I am using MvcConfiguration (my class implements WebMvcConfigurer as WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated).
I changed the prefix mapping to `resolver.setPrefix("webapp/resources/WEB-INF/view/")` to reflect this structure: https://ibb.co/9qB9bh6.
The error I get: 'There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500)
'uriTemplate' must not be null'. 
It seems related to REST methods. I have REST methods in the same controller but annotated them with @ResponseBody and changed the controller class annotation to @Controller.

Comment: Thank you, i have updated the answer (now implementing WebMvcCinfigurer).Just  try giving resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/") , and keep WEB-INF under webapp and not under resources.That is 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF'

Comment: Doesn't work :( I hope to resolve it this weekend and will let you know how.

Comment: Try enabling the spring-boot trace logs to understand what actually is the issue. Maybe the jsp files are not getting compiled properly.

Comment: The RequestMapping for the path before the view names (which I had from my previously-created REST endpoints) was not being mapped properly. We followed the initial tutorial more closely (especially in terms of package structure) and moved the views to their own controller (leaving the REST endpoints in the initial controller). This fixed the issue.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your findings @Konstantina